# Why the DictionaryValue is converted to ScalarValue in Serilog in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, console, serilog

My Serilog configuration is the following:

```
    LevelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;

    var loggerConfiguration =
        new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LevelSwitch)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Conditional(
                IsDictionaryValue,
                cfg => cfg.Console());

    services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());
```

where the `IsDictionaryValue` is defined as:

```
    static bool IsDictionaryValue(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("LOG_TEST", out LogEventPropertyValue value))
        {
            return value is DictionaryValue;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

trying to log trace and information message:

```
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "val1", 1 },
        { "val2", 2 },
        { "val3", "_3" },
    };

    logger.LogTrace("{@LOG_TEST}", dict);

    logger.LogInformation("{@LOG_TEST}", dict);
```

**The question is:**
Why in ASP.NET Core web app the log trace message correctly creates `DictionaryValue` and the result of `IsDictionaryValue` is `true`, but when I log information message, the `LogEventPropertyValue` value is `ScalarValue`.

**BUT**
This "bug" is only in ASP.NET Core web app. When I use the same Serilog configuration in Console app, both LogTrace and LogInformation, correctly represents the `dict` dictionary as `DictionaryValue`.

**Update:**
type of `LogEventPropertyValue` in `DictionaryValue`

| Log method | Console App | Web app |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LogTrace | DictionaryValue | DictionaryValue |
| LogDebug | DictionaryValue | DictionaryValue |
| LogInformation | DictionaryValue | **ScalarValue** |
| LogWarning | DictionaryValue | **ScalarValue** |
| LogError | DictionaryValue | **ScalarValue** |
| LogCritical | DictionaryValue | **ScalarValue** |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**
In ASP.NET Core are registered some default `LoggerProviders` like:

```
1. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLogger
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.DebugLogger
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.EventSourceLogger
4. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger
```

and when you configure serilog

```
services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());
```

the fifth `LoggerProvider` was added:

```
5. Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger
```

The default configuration for other providers is `LogLevel:Information`. This is the reason why `LogTrace` and `LogDebug` works in Web app.
So if you call `LogInformation` the first four logger providers hits the `TState` in

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{
    internal class Logger : ILogger
    {
        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    }
}
```

and it converts the original `dictionary` to `string`. And when the fifth logger provider (out `SerilogLogger`) comes to play, it cannot resolve `DictionaryValue` because the `TState` is `string`

**The solution:**
Set the `SerilogLogger` as the first `LoggerProvider`:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
            .ConfigureLogging(cfg => cfg
                .ClearProviders()
                .AddSerilog()
                .AddConsole()
                .AddDebug()
                .AddEventSourceLogger()
                .AddEventLog());
    }
```

and because the `SerilogLoggerProvider` is registered in `Program.cs` within `IHostBuilder`, the `AddSerilog()` in `services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddSerilog());` is not necessary.

```
services.AddLogging();
```